# Turn a directory into a partition

Tags: partitioning, backup, home-directory

I'm a linux newbie and I know this sounds crazy, but is there any way to turn the /home/user folder (or any other folder, for that matter) into a separate partition (without having to first create a new empty partition and move the files there afterwards)? The reason for that is that I don't have enough free space in my HD, and I want to format and reinstall ubuntu, preserving the /home/user directory.

If the community could help me out here, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: creating a partition from your free space is not that difficult, and tecnically you don't have to move the files, but to rsync them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. You have to create a new partition and move the files.

Answer (score 1):

You could have done this during the installation itself. Instead of creating a partition with mount point "/", you could have created separate partitions for /home , /boot etc.
This would have done the job

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new partition and set it up as a home partition. [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) you can see how.